# spring-kafka consumer throws deserialization exception when producer produces messages

Tags: spring-kafka

I am new to spring-kafka. Basically I have a spring boot app with Spring Kafka (spring-kafka 2.9.0 and spring-boot 2.6.4). As long as I run the program as producer or consumer I don’t see run into any issues.

But if I run the same program to produce messages to topic-A and listen to messages coming from topic-B at the same time then I run into deserialization errors in Producer (which is confusing) while sending messages to topic-A. Producer and consumer have their own configs and producer produces a different POJO to serialize and consumer de-serializes a different POJO, but I am failing to understand why consumer is invoked while messages are being produced by producer.

Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, can you post your code?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Such a project would be very helpful for all of us to determine the problem and figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, on further investigation I found that the issue was not with spring-kafka. Its an symptom of some other issue. The issue itself is that I am using a connector to read and write messages to a database. For some reason when producer publishes the message, sink connector is publishing messages to topic-B. Since kafka-consumer is listening to topic-B and is not configured to deserialize the newly published messages it runs into exceptions. This has nothing to do with Spring Kafka